# Default value of select using ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the default value for select box, but I have hard time trying to do it, and I have no idea what is wrong. Here is my code

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="newQuestion.positionOnSurvey=vm.questionsPositions[0]" ng-model="newQuestion.positionOnSurvey">
                                    <option ng-repeat="position in vm.questionsPositions track by $index" value="{{position}}">{{position}}</option>
</select>
```

vm.questionsPositions[0] = 5, so this is not a problem. I am not initializing newQuestion in my controller, but it should be not a case with ng-init ?

UPDATE:

Now I am initializing the field like this, but it is still not working.

```
vm.newQuestion = {};
vm.newQuestion.positionOnSurvey = vm.questionsPositions[0];

<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.newQuestion.positionOnSurvey">
    <option ng-repeat="position in vm.questionsPositions track by $index" value="{{position}}">{{position}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As a side note, is there a reason you're not using the [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) syntax?

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: What do you want as the default value? the first element in the array? or something general like `Choose something` ?

Comment: Specific element from an array, all this code is inside div with ng-repeat = "question in questions". I want the default value to be question.position.

Comment: What is your **vm.questionsPositions** values and what you want to show initially in select list.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use controller to initialize the value and better way to create drop-down list using **ng-options**

Like:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="newQuestion.positionOnSurvey" ng-options="position for position in vm.questionsPositions"></select>
```

**Controller:**

```
        $scope.vm ={};
        $scope.newQuestion ={};
        $scope.vm.questionsPositions = [12,14];
        $scope.newQuestion.positionOnSurvey = $scope.vm.questionsPositions[0];
```

so initial value in select list is 12

Answer (score 0):

You could try to init `$newQuestion.positionOnSurvey` in your controller with your default value, so the selector at the view will have an initial value.

Comment: It is not working: $scope.newQuestion = {};
  $scope.newQuestion.positionOnSurvey = 0;

Comment: is 0 (or whatever is $scope.newQuestion.positionOnSurvey default value) an option of the selector?

Answer (score 0):

> The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat` [...]. Besides this case, you should use **controllers** rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.

According to the `ngInit` API, I'd suggest setting the initial value of your selection on your controller.

see: [controller guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#setting-up-the-initial-state-of-a-scope-object)

Comment: I updated code according to guide, but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="vm.newQuestion.positionOnSurvey=vm.questionsPositions[0]" ng-model="newQuestion.positionOnSurvey">
                                    <option ng-repeat="position in vm.questionsPositions track by $index" value="{{position}}">{{position}}</option>
</select>
```

You are declaring "newQuestion" variable in vm object. So, you can access that variable in html as "vm.newQuestion"

Answer (score 0):

You sure that ng-options is not working? This code should do the trick.

```
<select ng-model="vm.newQuestion.positionOnSurvey" ng-options="position for position in vm.questionsPositions"></select>
```